# Animate UV maps in Image Editor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

After unwrapping a texture in blender cycles in the image editor, is it possible to animate like scale, rotation and etc. of the unwrapped texture?
I want to be able to animate the unwrapped area. 
[image]

Comment: there is a plugin that will allow you to animate the UVs: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Animation/AnimAll watch: https://youtu.be/xlJ71XChDuY?t=867

Comment: Is it just a script i can run in the text editor?